# É realmente preciso especificar o elemento HTML antes da classe no seletor de uma regra CSS?

Tags: html, css, seletores

Eu não sei se isso vale para todos, mas o único elemento o qual estou interessado é a `<div>`. Por exemplo:

```
div.classe1 { /*...*/ }

.clase1 { /*...*/ }
```

Qual a diferença entre os dois exemplos? Eu consigo fazer as mesmas coisas com os dois casos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A diferença é que no primeiro caso, você só selecionará as `div`s que contenham a classe `classe1`, diferentemente do segundo exemplo, que selecionará **qualquer elemento** com a classe `classe1`.

Um breve exemplo:

```css
.exemplo1 {
  color: red;
}

div.exemplo2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="exemplo1">Sou um &lt;span&gt; com a classe `exemplo1`;</span>
<div class="exemplo1">Sou uma &lt;div&gt; com a classe `exemplo1`;</div>
<span class="exemplo2">Sou um &lt;span&gt; com a classe `exemplo2`;</span>
<div class="exemplo2">Sou uma &lt;div&gt; com a classe `exemplo2`;</div>
```

Como você pode ver acima, quando não temos um seletor de elemento precedendo a classe, todos os elementos são selecionados. Isso já não acontece no segundo caso (`exemplo2`), em que somente as `div`s são selecionadas.

#### Para um aprofundamento maior:

- [Seletores CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Getting_Started/Seletores);
- [Os 30 seletores que você deve memorizar](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048).

Answer (score 4):

Se existir outros elementos que não sejam uma `div` com a mesma classe, ao usar a informação `div.classe1{}`, a classe será aplicada apenas ao elemento que seja uma `div`, e não será aplicada a outros elementos (`p`, `span`, por exemplo).

Eu, particularmente, prefiro usar `div.classe1{}`, pois ao ver o código do CSS, eu consigo perceber mais rapidamente que aquela classe está sendo aplicada em um ou mais elementos que sejam uma `div`.

Em casos onde o CSS vá crescendo muito com várias classes, acredito ser melhor.
Se você for utilizar essa classe em apenas uma div, seria melhor criar um `id` para a div, e utilizar a regra apenas para ela, assim:

No HTML:

```
<div id="minhadiv">Teste</div>
```

No CSS:

```
#minhadiv { .... }
```

Dessa forma você aplica a regra diretamente à div específica com esse `id`.